# copy and past last used column range into next column range

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new on VBA and I have a problem on copy and past the last used column in range into new column range as I read through previous article, it is specific only copy and past the whole column into next column as below

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim col As Integer
  col = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
  Columns(col).Copy
  Columns(col + 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
  Columns(col).Select
  Selection.Copy
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
  :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

From above code, I can copy the whole column to next column and hard code previous column, but I don't know how to copy only some range in the row such as: Column E, copy only Row 5:10. Please kindly help me on this matter.

And one more thing, what is the code change if I need to create Macro Bottom in another active sheet?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim col As Integer
  col = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
  Range(Cells(5, col), Cells(10, col)).Copy Destination:=Range(Cells(5, col + 1), Cells(10, col + 1))
End Sub
```